# Android Studio Emulator doesn’t open the app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator, emulation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NH8Q.png)

****The emulator opens but without launching the app.****

Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

14:15   Emulator: added library vulkan-1.dll

14:15   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: IniFile.cpp:235: Failed to open .ini file C:\Users\ÐŸÐ¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒ.android\emu-update-last-check.ini for writing.

Comment: ÐŸÐ¾Ð»ÑŒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»ÑŒ. seems like your username is quite complex. try some english path ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it happens because that strangely named folder is originally named in Russian, but I can't rename it as it is an administrative folder